# JavaScript XSS prevention - what to check

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, xss

I am trying to prevent a XSS attack on a form. I have read the [following](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/preventing), but I am not clear on how to implement their suggestion.

I want to prevent the attack, so I need to check the value of the `username`. It can be attacked by the following for example:

```
curl -X POST -d "username=%3C%2Fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Efunction()%7bqxsspbCegNO0%7d%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E&forgotUsernameBtn=1" https://xyz/mypage.do >> test.txt
```

**Question:**

What javascript do I add to get it to do the check (I belive to call the `htmlEncode` and `jsEscape` functions)?

I have the following:

**jsp**

```
<script>
    function htmlEncode(str){
        return String(str).replace(/[^\w. ]/gi, function(c){
            return '&#'+c.charCodeAt(0)+';';
        });
    }
    function jsEscape(str){
        return String(str).replace(/[^\w. ]/gi, function(c){
            return '\\u'+('0000'+c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);
        });
    }
</script>


                        <html:form action="forgotUsername" styleId="loginFormBean" styleClass="margin-1rem-top">
                            <div>
                                <div class="form-floating field">
                                    <input autocomplete="off" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$"
                                           type="text" id="username" name="username" required class="form-control"
                                           value="${loginForm.username}" placeholder="Email"/>
                                    <label for="username">Email</label>
                                    <span class="autoComplete-img">
                                        <img src="assets/images/envelope-gray.svg" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="actions margin-1rem-top text-center">
                                    <button type="submit" id="submitButton" name="forgotUsernameBtn"
                                            class="submit butn-blue butn-md butn"
                                            onclick = "sanitize();">
                                        Forgot Username
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </html:form>
```

Comment: Do you display the data send by the user anywhere?

Comment: Like @Konrad says, are you also showing what the user submits on your webpage, because placing any of that data into server side db etc, is not an issue for XSS attack, the attack is when you re-display this data.  This is dangerous because now the attack is able to run code in the same domain as your website, this could leak Session Data / Cookies to some 3rd party.

Comment: It is displaying the data again here: `${loginForm.username}`, so I think the fix may be to do this: `value="${fn:escapeXml(loginForm.username)}"`.

Comment: I don't use JSP server side stuff, but a quick google that looks correct.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I think I am in the right direction now, appreciate the guidace.  I think I may need to do:  `email = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(email));` in the java code. This is for any variables that will get displayed on the client, e.g. the email they submit.

Answer (score 1):

> What javascript do I add to get it to do the check

**None**.

The point at which you need to defend against XSS is when user input is inserted into code (usually an HTML document).

e.g. You would use JSP to convert the user input to safe HTML if you were displaying the username in an HTML document.

Trying to do this with client-side JavaScript before the form is submitted is fruitless because:

- It is easily bypassed by an attacker (as is the case with the `curl` example in your question!)
- All sorts of things might be done to the username (such as being inserted into a database or an email) before or instead of being inserted in to an HTML document, and encoding to make it safe for HTML will make it look like junk in other contexts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but please can you give me some guidance on what to do to prevent the attack? Sorry, I am a bit confused.

Comment: @Richard — I refer you to the two paragraphs immediately after the word "None."

Comment: So are you saying that preventing XSS is not possible? - It does't have to use javascript when the user is on the client, but also when a malicious script is run, e.g. the `curl` command.

Comment: No. I'm saying that the place that XSS needs to be addressed is in the code which inserts the user data into an HTML document.

Comment: See also https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/preventing — specifically the part with the heading **Encode data on output** (although it forgets to mention `&` which needs encoded too).

Comment: Apologies for sounding ignorant, but I am trying to understand.  So if I get it, I think I will need to do the following: `<script>document.body.innerHTML = htmlEncode(untrustedValue)</script>` and `<script>document.write('<script>x="'+jsEscape(untrustedValue)+'";<\/script>')</script>` when the page loads. But I don't know what the `untrustedValue` is or how to set it.

Comment: In the example you give (`curl -X POST -d etc`) there isn't an untrusted value that client JS can read.

Comment: Your question starts with "I am trying to prevent a XSS attack on a form." — but forms are a means of letting the user type some data and sends it *somewhere* to do *something* with it. That *something* might make the *somewhere* vulnerable to XSS in which case you might have to take steps to deal with it, but how you do that depends on what the *something* is, and since the *somewhere* appears to be a servlet or some JSP  those steps almost certainly need to be done in server-side Java and not client-side JavaScript.

Comment: `curl -X POST -d "username=</script><script>function(){qxsspbCegNO0};</script>&forgotUsernameBtn=1" https://xyz/mypage.do >> test.txt`

Comment: the untrusted value is: `qxsspbCegNO0 `

Comment: @Richard — No it isn't. The untrusted value is `</script><script>function(){qxsspbCegNO0};</script>&forgotUsernameBtn=1`, but it is POST data so you **can't read it with client-side JS**, since you can't read it with client-side JS you can't insert it into an HTML document with client-side JS, so your client-side JS can't be vulnerable to XSS, so you can't defend against XSS with that client-side JS.

Comment: I am confused, because our webpage was flagged as being vulnerable against the above script, e.g. when that `curl` is executed, it creates html containing: `<li>Username for </script><script>function(){qxsspbCegNO0};</script> not found, please contact the help desk.</li>`, you can see that the malicious text gets submitted. So does that mean I need to check this on the server instead of the client?

Comment: Yes. You need to check this on the server instead of the client. I have said that at least 4 times already. Probably most clearly here: "e.g. You would use JSP to convert the user input to safe HTML if you were displaying the username in an HTML document."

Comment: I am trying the following in the jsp:  `value="${fn:escapeXml(loginForm.username)}"`.